# Is there a way to capture a Hyper-V VHD image of a running Linux (Centos) server?

Tags: linux, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd, disk-image

I have a linux server running Centos (actually its a PBX running Trixbox) that I want to migrate to a Hyper-V based VM so that the physical server can be repurposed.

Is it possible to capture a VHD image directly from a Linux server?

Answer (score 2):

There are some converters to VMWare's vmdk disk format - qemu-img (QEMU), clonehd (VirtualBox) or the VMWare Converter would do. You can then use something like [vmdk2vhd](http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry8.aspx) or SCVMM to convert to VHD.

Comment: +1 qemu-img is a great way to convert raw disks, vmdk, vhd, qcow, etc.